# xsl ancestor-or-self not return result

Tags: xslt, ancestor

I have problem when try to for-each every parent of node. I have XML like this:

> ```
> <item name="news" id="77">
>   <items>
>     <item id="102" />
>     <item id="103" />        
>   </items>
> </item>    
> <item id="86">
>   <items>
>     <item id="122">
>       <items>
>         <item id="6" />
>         <item id="9" />
>       </items>
>     </item>
>     <item id="12">
>       <items>
>         <item id="13" />
>         <item id="18" />
>         <item id="19" />
>       </items>
>     </item>
>   </items>
> </item>
> <item name="sitemap" id="88" />
> ```

And in template I try like this:

```
<xsl:template name="render">
<xsl:param name="length" />
<xsl:param name="item" />
  <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::item[@id='9']">        
    some code
  </xsl:for-each>      
<xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
```

Help me please if you can.

**UPD:**

I want to get some like a menu (if choosed option with id=9):

```
<ul>
 <li>77</li>
 <li>
  86
  <ul>
   <li>
    122
    <ul>
     <li>6</li>
     <li>9</li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li>12</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>88</li>
</ul>
```

My XSLT (I think about it) is not good:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<ul>
<xsl:call-template name="render">
  <xsl:with-param name="item" select="item[@id='9']" />
  <xsl:with-param name="length" select="0" />
</xsl:call-template>
</ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="render">
  <xsl:param name="length" />
  <xsl:param name="item" />
  <xsl:for-each select="$item/ancestor-or-self::item[@id='9']">        
    <xsl:if test="position()=length">
      <xsl:variable name="current" select="." />
      <xsl:for-each select="../item">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test=".=current">
            <li class="selectedItem">
              <p>
                <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
              </p>
              <xsl:call-template name="render">
                <xsl:with-param name="length" select="$lenght + 1" />
                <xsl:with-param name="item" select="$item" />
              </xsl:call-template>
            </li>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <li>
              <p>
                <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
              </p>
            </li>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>      
<xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Your question is not particularly clear, and is more of a statement than a question.  Can you be a bit more specific... in particular, what EXACTLY are you looking for as an output.

Comment: What is the current node when the `render` template is called? Could you show us some more of your XSLT?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't made your problem clear, but I wonder if you are perhaps looking for ancestors of the parameter node $item, rather than ancestors of the context node? If so, that would be

```
select="$item/ancestor-or-self::item[@id='9']
```

However, in your sample XML, the only node with @id='9' isn't the ancestor of anything, so I suspect I am groping in the dark.

Answer (score 1):

So essentially you want to generate a tree structure where all the nodes are "collapsed" except the one with a specified id. I would approach this differently:

```
<xsl:template match="items | menu" mode="menu">
  <xsl:param name="targetId" />
  <ul>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="item" mode="menu">
      <xsl:with-param name="targetId" select="$targetId"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item" mode="menu">
  <xsl:param name="targetId" />
  <li>
    <xsl:if test="@id = $targetId">
      <xsl:attribute name="class">selectedItem</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>

    <!-- expand the branch only if it contains the target id -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="items[.//@id = $targetId]" mode="menu">
      <xsl:with-param name="targetId" select="$targetId"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </li>
</xsl:template>
```

And when you want to render a menu for a particular id you just say

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/menu" mode="menu">
  <xsl:with-param name="targetId" select="'9'"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

(Here I'm assuming your original XML has a `<menu>` root element wrapped around the top level set of `item` elements, if that's not the case you'll have to adjust the match and select expressions appropriately).

If you want to also display the level below the target id (e.g. include the 6, 9 layer when the target id is 122) then just change

```
    <xsl:apply-templates select="items[.//@id = $targetId]" mode="menu">
```

to

```
    <xsl:apply-templates select="items[current()//@id = $targetId]" mode="menu">
```

Answer (score 0):

look at the following solution

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:variable name="home" select="//item[@name='home']" />


<xsl:variable name="current_item" select="//item[@id = '55']" />

<xsl:variable name="parents_line" select="$current_item/ancestor-or-self::item" />

<xsl:variable name="path">
<xsl:for-each select="$parents_line">
   <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
   <xsl:if test="position()=last()">/</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:variable> 

<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:call-template name="menu" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="menu">
    <xsl:param name="level" select="1" />
    <xsl:param name="start" select="$home" />

    <ul>
      <xsl:for-each select="$start/items/item">
       <xsl:variable name="current_id" select="@id" />
        <li>
          <xsl:value-of select="@name" />

          <xsl:if test="contains($path, concat('/', $current_id, '/') )">
            <xsl:call-template name="menu">
              <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level+1" />
              <xsl:with-param name="start" select="." />
            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:if>
        </li>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```